# GL drawings in CCSpriteBatchNode - cocos2d

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I have several objects inherited from CCSprite. Each object has CCSprite children and overridden draw method. I'd like to add these objects to a single batch node (CCSpriteBatchNode). Everything works fine, but my drawings performed in draw method are not displayed. Is there a way to perform any GL drawings in these objects combined into one batch node?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

CCSpriteBatchNode is drawing the sprites for you, otherwise it wouldn't be able to speed up the drawing of its child sprites. At the same time it couldn't possibly know how to batch your custom draw code. That's why the `draw` method of CCSprites added to a CCSpriteBatchNode simply isn't called.

Comment: Thanks! I've decided to draw all stuff in CCSpriteBatchNode's draw method. Everything works well, but the primitives are drawn over CCSpriteBatchNode's children. I've modified zOrder of children, but without any effect. Can you please let me know how to draw primitives in object inherited from CCSpriteBatchNode under its children?

Comment: If you inherit from CCSpriteBatchNode and override the draw method, you'll be calling [super draw]. If that call is before your own drawing code, your custom drawing should be in front of the sprites.